# Google analytics set up with wrong domain

Tags: google-analytics

I have recently embedded Google Analytics into a site using the default embed code.

```
<script>
    (function (i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
        i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r; i[r] = i[r] || function () {
            (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
        }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date(); a = s.createElement(o),
        m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]; a.async = 1; a.src = g; m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
    })(window, document, 'script', '//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

    ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1', 'MYDOMAIN.COM');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

However I had MYDOMAIN.COM set to an incorrect domain.

The views for the site seem very low, however, I can see myself there as a visitor in the real time scanner.

What effect would setting the domain incorrectly have had? How does Google use this parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Real time scanner works in a different way from normal tracking, as in you still see real time visitors most of the time even when your tracking is mis-configured.

The setting in question allows you to track different domains (or domain and a subdomain) on one accounts. The effect of this is tracking not registering correctly for the domain you want to track.

Comment: Do you think this would cause page views to be 'lost'? I noticed the track multiple domains option has gone

Comment: Yes I am pretty sure that will be the cause of it. If you correct and update analytics code you should start seeing real page views in 2 to 24-hours.

Answer (score 1):

Google analytics tries to set its cookies to the domain provided.  If you get it wrong, the cookies won't stick. This will cause several problems:

- each page view will be a new session
- pages per session will be "1"
- There will be no returning visitors

Comment: But this wouldn't affect page views or unique visitor counts?

Comment: Page views would be accurate, but unique visitors would be vastly inflated.